# How to write R packages that prompt messages when loaded?

Tags: r, r-package

I am writing an R package. I want it to prompt a message that might include information like how to properly use the package, the limitation of the package, and also politely asks for citation if using when users load (require(), library()). Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 4):

If you create a function called `.onLoad()` in the package, it is executed when package is loaded. Traditionally the function is placed in a file called called zzz.R.  For example:

```
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname){
    msg <- paste("Loading", pkgname)
    cat(msg) 
}
```

Be sure to read `help(.onLoad)` for some important guidance on good practice.

Comment: Thank you so much! That is what I am looking for.